# Will this PHP script leak memory?

Tags: php, memory-management, garbage-collection

I have a PHP script that runs in the background for a while (usually a few minutes, but this could be up to an hour or so). It contains a loop in which I need to create an object. I'm currently using the same name every time like this:

```
while (!$job_finished) {
    $x = new MyClass();
    $x->doStuff();
    $x->doMoreStuff();
    unset ($x);

    // more code here
}
```

Since I'm creating $x repeatedly with the same name, will garbage collection properly clean up memory? Or should I use an array over $x such as

```
   $x[$i] = new MyClass();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I don't need to use the array. The unset() command will destroy the object and therefore I shouldn't worry. This is in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) where it states:

> The destructor method will be called as soon as there are no other references to a particular object, or in any order during the shutdown sequence.

I tested it with the following code and it shows the destruct method being called before the end of the script indeed.

```
<?php

class A {
  function __destruct() {
    echo "cYa later!!\n";
  }
}

$a = new A();
unset($a);

echo "hello";
sleep(10);
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, if you are keeping object references to an array, it will not release memory & will fail in last.

However, your code example shown will not issue memory problems as you are not keeping object's reference & overriding it always in loop.